# problema al abrir IDLE : IDLE subprocess didnt make connection

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esto es lo que dice:

```
IDLE subprocess didnt make connection. 
Either IDLE cant start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection.
```

Ps: ya intenté con el firewall

Comment: ¿cuando te genera ese mensaje?

Comment: Si intento iniciar el IDLE de python

Comment: Tambien al ejecutar

Comment: ¿como se llaman los archivos que esta intentando ejecutar o los que ha creado? ¿tienes archivos llamados como random.py o similares?

Comment: tengo estos 4 archivos:     
random.cpython-37.pyc     
random.py     
test_random.py      
test_random_things.py      
fueron los que aparecieron en la busqueda

Comment: No hablo sobre los archivos que provee python por defecto sino lo que tu has creado. Otra cosa que podrias probar es ejecutar IDLE como administrador.

Comment: Yo no he creado ningun archivo aparte de uno en el que intento usar tkinter. alli fue la primera manifestacion del error

Comment: y ¿cual es el nombre de ese archivo?

Comment: Y al ejecutar como administrador todavia me sale el error (No tengo suficiente reputacion para el chat)

Comment: se llama tkinter.py

Comment: nunca nombres a un archivo con el nombre de una libreria ya existente, ese te genera ese problema, cambia el nombre a tkinter_prueba.py

Comment: ok voy a intentar

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS

Comment: Te hubiera dado un voto pero estamos discutiendo en los comentarios

Comment: Voy a publicar una respuesta, y en ella podras marcarla como correcta. :-)